# Spring MVC prevent url changing when returning static html

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, url

I have Spring MVC + Angular app. 
SpringMVC only "view" task is to forward to Angular index.html page which is in resources/static folder.

This works and when I call url localhost/did my angular app appers.
Problem is that URL in browser changes to localhost/static/static and I would like to prevent it.

I tried numerous methods described here, but nothing works.

**AppController**

```
@Controller
public class AppController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String test(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        return "forward:/static/index.html";
}
```

I tried different combinations of adding/removing forward keyword and paths

**MvcConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("static/**").addResourceLocations("static/");
    }

/*
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }
*/
/*
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry){
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/static/index.html");
    }
*/
/*
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/static/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix("*.html");
        internalResourceViewResolver.set
        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }
*/

/*
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH");
    }
*/

}
```

Commented parts of code are previous methods I tried.

**Index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ui</title>
  <base href="static/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.3ff695c00d717f2d2a11.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.66a2e3e0a1f871fa391a.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.8673ca52f204ca8863f2.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in combination of resourceHandler and  settings.
Correct configuration is

```
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("static/");
}
```

and

```
enter <base href="./">
```